# Como se traduz "Enjoyee Meeting" para o português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Boa tarde, me deparei com essa expressão e gostaria de entender o significado, especificamente da palavra "Enjoyee", entendo o que significa: Enjoy e Enjoyed.

Obrigado.

Comment: Em que contexto? Pode dar uma frase de exemplo ou um link de referência?

Comment: Então não teria um contexto

Comment: Esta sem contexto não se compreenderia. Mas tem contexto: o Google encontra «enjoyee meeting» numa única frase que se repete em cinco páginas do mesmo site: «I always enjoyee meeting new people.» Isto não é inglês padrão; o padrão é *I always enjoy meeting*... De qualquer modo isto seria uma pergunta par o ELL; não é uma questão de língua portuguesa.

Comment: Voto para fechar. A pergunta é sobre uma confusão na interpretação do inglês, não sobre língua portuguesa. O site adequado para estas dúvidas de inglês é o [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim sem mais contexto é difícil dizer com certeza, mas em Inglês o [sufixo *-ee*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ee) é frequentemente acrescentado no final de verbos, transformando-os em substantivos, para denominar aquele a quem é feita a determinada acção.

Por exemplo

- *Examine* (Examinar) > *Examiner* (Examinador) > *Examinee* (Examinado)
- *Employ* (Empregar) > *Employer* (Empregador) > *Employee* (Empregado)

Por esta lógica de pensamento, penso que não temos muitas palavras equivalentes na nossa língua portuguesa, mas temos

- *Enjoy* (Desfrutar, Apreciar, Aproveitar, Divertir) > *Enjoyee* (Desfrutador, Apreciador, aquele que se diverte ou aproveita)

Aproveitador acho que já têm uma conotação diferente mais negativa, de parasita ou de quem tira partido de alguma situação prejudicando outros.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria saber.. Obrigado

Comment: Pois, é muito arriscado responder a uma pergunta destas sem contexto.Vê o meu comentário à pergunta. De qualquer modo, por essa lógica, seria *apreciado*, não *apreciador*.

Comment: Hum, pois nesse contexto parece me mais um erro ortográfico do que o significado que indiquei.

Comment: Oh, não ligues, @Jacinto , devo estar com loucura temporária de fim-de-semana...

Comment: @ANeves Calculei que fosse :) Mas loucura de pedras ou de varrimento?

Comment: Duarte, eu vi no google um *enjoyee [qualquer coisa]*, e pareceu-me que era deliberado, como na fala prolongaríamos o ***y*** para ênfase.

Comment: Hahaha! Ah sim também há essa possibilidade, para enfatizar a palavra ou dar uma entoação mais prolongada.

Comment: Pela lógica de *examinee* e *employee*, não deveria ser um encontro daqueles que se divertem, mas um encontro daqueles à custa de quem os outros se divertem...

Comment: Sim também poderia ser interpretado dessa forma, mas para ser sincero nunca ouvi esta transformação aplicada ao verbo *enjoy* em particular, por isso não tenho a certeza de que significado exacto poderia ter, já que parece uma utilização não standard.

Comment: Uma vez que a pergunta foi modificada, acho que poderia ser tirada do "hold", para que possa ser respondida.

Comment: Jogando a expressão no google, todos os resultados que obtive apontam para uma única origem, um texto repetido em diversos sites de encontros eróticos/amorosos, em que fica claro que é um erro de digitação ou de ortografia, e a construção intentada é "enjoy meeting", "gosto de encontrar".